# Finding distinct values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using Access.
I have the following query;

```
SELECT instruments.inst , instruments.predicted, instruments.prediction
FROM instruments 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT inst, MAX(prediction) AS [predictions]
FROM instruments
GROUP BY inst ) groupedtt
ON instruments.inst = groupedtt.inst
AND instruments.prediction = groupedtt.predictions
```

What I want to do is, if the predictions of INST are the same, I want it to only return one record. Currently if the predictions are the same, then it will show all these records. All I want is for it to display one records for each.

I've tried distinct, but it doesn't seem to work, and the output is the same.

Sample data

```
Inst  instrument        prediction
16  BassSaxophone       0.9
16  B-flatclarinet      0.9
```

Desired output would be to display one of these two records, sql to automatically chose one of these, rather than displaying both records. E.g.

```
Inst  instrument        prediction
16  BassSaxophone       0.9
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with sample data and desired results?  I don't understand what you want the output to be.

Comment: @GordonLinoff editied, hope this makes more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another answer for you: DISTINCT doesn't work, because the records are different. If you want one result line *per* inst and prediction, you *group by* inst and prediction.

```
SELECT instruments.inst , MAX(instruments.predicted), instruments.prediction
FROM instruments 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT inst, MAX(prediction) AS [predictions]
FROM instruments
GROUP BY inst ) groupedtt
ON instruments.inst = groupedtt.inst
AND instruments.prediction = groupedtt.predictions
GROUP BY instruments.inst , instruments.prediction;
```

I like my other answer better, though :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite your query thus:

```
select inst, predicted, prediction
from instruments i1
where not exists
(
  select *
  from instruments i2
  where i2.inst = i1.inst
  and i2.prediction > i1.prediction
);
```

I.e. get all instruments for which no instrument of the same inst with a greater prediction exists.

Now to only get one record per prediction we simply extend the where clause.

```
select inst, predicted, prediction
from instruments i1
where not exists
(
  select *
  from instruments i2
  where i2.inst = i1.inst
  and (i2.prediction > i1.prediction or 
      (i2.prediction = i1.prediction and i2.instrument > i1.instrument))
);
```